# Is android.intent.action.MAIN and Intent.ACTION_MAIN are Same

Tags: android

I think it is not Same because

i have two Activities `A` -> `B` , and in `B` i am using , `startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN) );` to get back to the `A` and i am getting list of application to navigate , but in this list i am not getting "My_Main_Activity" name  `A` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both have same values.The code that you are using is to list all applications that has intent filter for this action Intent.ACTION_MAIN. This code used for calling external application You should use finish(); in your Activity B to get back to Activity A.
or you can simply use following code

```
startActivity(new Intent(B.this, A.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setClass(B.this,A.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: why , startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN) ); not working .

Comment: Because every package of each app contains a MAIN intent so android doesnt know which to open

Comment: As u r a begginer i use this ,the below one is more optimised code but is work same as this.